# Website going down intermittenty, but server is always up

Tags: web, dns, http-status-code-301, no-www

I have recently set up my domain, but my problem is when I navigate with/without www, the results are inconsistent. They are supposed to point to the same page, but sometimes, the www site has broken links to non-www components (e.g.: when I load http://www.my-domain.com, and if I have a resource referred as http://my-domain.com/navi.css, it breaks)

Have tried 301 rewriting, but it's not always consistent. What do I need to do to ensure 100% uptime for my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because of a couple of reasons:

- Your DNS has not propagated yet, meaning if you recently just changed DNS on the domain name give it up to 48 hours and flush cache from your browser.
- The domain DNS is pointing to different IP addresses from your www. or * A records.
- There is a problem with the hosting configuration  (unlikely if you are using CPanel or any hosting control panel as this is mostly automated).

Also you should pick either with or without www for consistency and better SEO results. Pick one and stick to it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Marking this as closed, but I am still having website issues. Will open a different thread since that does not seem to be www/non-www related.